# Include and Build SDL2 on QT for Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, sdl

I want to rewrite my huge app (*written on VisualStudio for Win and XCode for Mac*) on QT, and build it for Android. 
I have [SDL2](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) source code, and I have written `.pro` file to include `include` folder of SDL:

```
android:
{
    INCLUDEPATH += C:\sdl2\include
}
```

But still I have a lot errors with SDL.
QT is new for me, so I need some advices. Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by compiling SDL on Eclipse, and including `.so` lib from it to QT.